# Align image in center and middle within div

Tags: html, css

I have following div

```
<div id="over" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%>
 <img src="img.png">
</div>
```

How to align the image so as to be located in the middle and center of div ?

Comment: Duplicate asked 2 minutes ago: [CSS: image middle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888118/css-image-middle)

Comment: Similar topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height/18516474

Comment: Consider selecting one answer as correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to position image in the center/middle both vertically and horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888118/how-to-position-image-in-the-center-middle-both-vertically-and-horizontally)

Answer (score 470):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#over img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="over" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%">
  <img src="http://www.garcard.com/images/garcard_symbol.png">
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Garconis/n3ooh4kt/)

Comment: `display: block;` was my pitfall. TnX

Comment: Following doesn't work. What's the mistake i am doing.
<html>
<head>
<style>
#over img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="over" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%"> 
 <img src="http://img8a.flixcart.com/image/tablet/f/k/t/asus-nexus-7-125x125-imadngwf2gk44dyd.jpeg">
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: If we don't use `display: block` the default is `display: inline` according to http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp.  Why do we need to use block?  I worked for me, but not sure why block will center the img and inline will not.

Comment: because inline don't move in the line, it is, indeed in line. so margin auto is ineffective.

Comment: This does not work. Take a look at aerdmans solution below. That works fine.

Comment: This doesn't align vertically

Answer (score 191):

```
<div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center">
<img src="img.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Very short and easy solution, but it appears to only be working with a fixed, non-percentage width and height. It does work with floats though so +1 for that. — http://jsfiddle.net/2s2nY/2/

Comment: but this is only doing the vertical-align but not the horizontal right?

Comment: It won't work if image's width larger than div's width.

Comment: This does not align vertically

Comment: If we remove display:table-cell; it works perfactly.

Answer (score 127):

This can also be done using the Flexbox layout:

**STATIC SIZE**

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    height: 300px; /* Or whatever */
    background-color: #000;
}

.child {
    width: 100px;  /* Or whatever */
    height: 100px; /* Or whatever */
    margin: auto;  /* Magic! */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <img class="child" src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300"/>
</div>
```

**DYNAMIC SIZE**

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #999;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
}

.child {
  margin: auto;  /* Magic! */
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img class="child" src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300"/>
</div>
```

I found the example in this [article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flexbox-examples), which does a great job explaining the how to use layout.

Comment: In the Static Size, there's no need for width and height for the child (at least in my version of Firefox).

Answer (score 90):

Seems to me that you also wanted that image to be vertically centered within the container. (I didn't see any answer that provided that)

[**Working Fiddle:**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/d89xh/)

1. Pure CSS solution
2. Not breaking the document flow (no floats or absolute positioning)
3. Cross browser compatibility (even IE6)
4. Completely responsive.

**HTML**

```
<div id="over">
    <span class="Centerer"></span>
    <img class="Centered" src="http://th07.deviantart.net/fs71/200H/f/2013/236/d/b/bw_avlonas_a5_beach_isles_wallpaper_image_by_lemnosexplorer-d6jh3i7.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#over
{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align: center; /*handles the horizontal centering*/
}
/*handles the vertical centering*/
.Centerer
{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.Centered
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Note:** this solution is good to align any element within any element.
for IE7, when applying the `.Centered` class on block elements, you will have to use another trick to get the `inline-block` working. (that because IE6/IE7 dont play well with inline-block on block elements)

Comment: Instead of having additional `span`, you could use the pseudo-element `:before`: http://jsfiddle.net/xaliber/cj6zhtp0/

Comment: @deathlock it's well known. but i was targeting old IE browsers (who didn't support pseudo elements).

Comment: @avrahamcool I see, I didn't realize that. Then what about wrapping the conditional `<!--[if lt IE 8]>` around the `span` ?

Comment: @deathlock why not leave the span as it is? Its not a burden for the browser.

Comment: It's not, but HTML should only be used for structure, not presentation. That job is left for CSS, hence the pseudo-element.

Comment: @deathlock although I agree with what you are saying, in this case I don't. because we still need to add support for old IE's, and I prefer to write a common solution, than polluting my code with conditionals, and add the relevant CSS.

Comment: What do you mean "Not breaking the document flow (no floats or absolute positioning)"?? What's the `#over { position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%;` ?

Comment: @Rodrigo this part is taken from the OP code. I didn't want to change his code. the centering technique works without it.

Comment: Ah ok. But it seems the flexbox layout is a better solution nowadays. It took me only two additional lines in the css, and no span tag.

Comment: @Rodrigo indeed, if you don't need to target older browsers this flexbox is the recommended approach.

Comment: @AlexBanman can you post a fiddle? I did this in a ton of places it's working perfectly.

Comment: @avrahamcool Here is the link to my page... http://alynxagency.com/success-stories/luxury-brand.php I'm beginning to wonder if this is going to be a nightmare because I'm working with flexible layouts AND Slick Slider. :(

Comment: and secondly: I did look through your code. it's infected with floats and static sizes (width, height in px) - so I think you are missing the goal of this answer. it's very upsetting to see comments like `this is not working` when you clearly misunderstood the concept.

Answer (score 68):

```css
img.centered {
   display: block;
   margin: auto auto;
}
```

Comment: this is very similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12282201/2351696)

Answer (score 51):

You can do this easily by using `display:flex` CSS property:

```
#over {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 29):

```css
#over {position:relative; text-align:center; 
       width:100%; height:100%; background:#CCC;}

#over img{
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

I still had some issues with other solution presented here. Finally this worked best for me:

```
<div class="parent">
    <img class="child" src="image.png"/>
</div>
```

css3:

```
.child {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Safari and Chrome */
 -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Firefox */
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* IE 9 */
 -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Opera */
 // I suppose you may like those too:
 // max-width: 80%;
 // max-height: 80%;
}
```

You can read more about that approach [at this page](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#hv3).

Comment: I had to also add parent css but your code worked perfectly!        position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 189px;

Answer (score 15):

Daaawx's answer works, but I think it would be cleaner if we eliminate the inline css.

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}

#over img {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 display: block;
}
div.example {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="example" id="over">
 <img src="http://www.garcard.com/images/garcard_symbol.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

Basically, setting right and left margin to auto will cause the image to center align.

```
<div id="over" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%>
<img src="img.png" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

This would be a simpler approach

```
#over > img{
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto; 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Well, we are in 2016... why not use flexbox?
It's also responsive. Enjoy.

```css
#over{
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="over">
 <img src="http://www.garcard.com/images/garcard_symbol.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

SIMPLE. 2018. FlexBox. To Check Browser Support - [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)
Minimal Solution:

```
div#over { 
   display: flex; 
   justify-content: center; 
   align-items: center; 
}
```

To get the widest browser support possible:

```
div#over { 
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: -ms-flex; 
   display: flex; 
   justify-content: center; 
   -ms-align-items: center; 
   align-items: center; 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

setting the *img* to **display:inline-block** while having set the superior *div* to **text-align:center** will do the job too

EDIT: to those folks who are playing with **display:inline-block** >>> don't forget that e.g. two divs like

```
<div>Div1 content</div>NOSPACEHERE<div>Div2 content</div>
```

really have no spaces between them (as seen here).

Just basic to avoid these (inline block inherent) gaps between them. These gaps can be seen between every two words I'm writing right now! :-) So .. hope this helps some of you.

Answer (score 6):

I've tried many approaches but only this one works for multiple inline elements inside a container div. Here is code to align everything in div at middle.

### CSS

```
.divContainer
{
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center; <!-- If you want horizontal center alignment -->
}
.divContainer > *
{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="divContainer">
    <span>Middle Text</span>
    <img src="test.png"/>
</div>
```

Sample code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/yogendrasinh/2vq0c68m/

Answer (score 5):

CSS File

```
.over {
    display : block;
    margin : 0px auto;
```

Answer (score 5):

The marked answer for this will not vertically align the image. A suitable solution for modern browsers is flexbox. A flex container can be configured to align its items both horizontally and vertically.

```
<div id="over" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
    <img src="img.png">
</div>
```

Comment: This solution answers the question and works, unlike the marked answer. Perhaps the down-voter could detail their decision to downvote?

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: That doesn't justify the downvote. The answer is technically correct and would help future readers. I've updated the answer body to honour the house rules but perhaps a more direct solution should be implemented by the core team since identifying code only answers is a trivial task.

Answer (score 5):

Just set parent div css property "text-align:center;"

```
 <div style="text-align:center; width:100%">
        <img src="img.png"> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me when you have to center align image and your parent div to image has covers whole screen. i.e. height:100% and width:100%

```
#img{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this minimal code:

```
<div class="outer">
    <img src="image.png"/>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```css
.outer{
  text-align: center;
}
.outer img{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

many answer suggests to use `margin:0 auto` but this works only when the element you trying to  make centered is not floating on left or right, that is `float` css attribute isn't set. In order to do this apply `display` attribute to `table-cell` and then apply margin of left and right to auto so your style will look like `style="display:table-cell;margin:0 auto;"`

Answer (score 2):

```
    <div>
    <p style="text-align:center; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; padding:0px;">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="image"/>
    </p>    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="over">
    <img src="img.png">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#over {
  text-align: center;
}

#over img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: It's best if you add some commentary and not just toss code out there.

Answer (score 2):

For center horizontally Just put

```
#over img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear:both;
}
```

Another method:

```
#over img {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

For center vertically Just put:

```
   #over img {

           vertical-align: middle;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
#image-id {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this did the trick for me.

```
<div class="CenterImage">
         <asp:Image ID="BrandImage" runat="server" />
</div>
```

'Note: do not have a css class assocaited to 'BrandImage' in this case

CSS:

```
.CenterImage {
    position:absolute; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%
}

.CenterImage img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use positioning. The following worked for me...

With zoom to the center of the image (image fills the div):

```
div{
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 70px; 
    height: 70px;  
    position: relative;
}
div img{
    min-width: 70px; 
    min-height: 70px;
    max-width: 250%; 
    max-height: 250%;    
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    bottom: -50%;
    right: -50%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Without zoom to the center of the image (image does **not** fill the div):

```
   div{
        display:block;
        overflow:hidden;
        width: 100px; 
        height: 100px;  
        position: relative;
    }
    div img{
        width: 70px; 
        height: 70px; 
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        bottom: 50%;
        right: 50%;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

most of the solutions don't work because a div with 100% height doesn't mean the full browser height.

using height: 100vh; works.

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#over {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>

<div id="over">
  <img src="test.png" alt="test" width="600">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a CSS Grid answer:

```css
#over {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  place-content: center;
}
```

`place-content: center` is shorthand for:

```css
.element {
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

This ensures the image is aligned centrally on both vertical and horizontal axes.

```html
<div id="over">
 <img src="img.png">
</div>
```

I'm assuming the inline styles you've applied to the div are for demonstration purposes, so have omitted them. The width of the div will inherently be 100% width of its parent container, I've added an arbitrary `height: 100vh` rule, but feel free to change it to whatever you need it to be.

For reference, this is from my guide on [how to center images with CSS](https://morganfeeney.com/guides/how-to-center-an-image-in-css#css-grid).

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look on this solution:

[Centering horizontally and vertically an image in a box](http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html)

```
<style type="text/css">
.wraptocenter {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: ...;
    height: ...;
}
.wraptocenter * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.wraptocenter {
    display: block;
}
.wraptocenter span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
}
</style>
<!--[if lt IE 8]-->
<style>
.wraptocenter span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
<!--[endif]-->

<div class="wraptocenter"><span></span><img src="..." alt="..."></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be creating separate styles for both the div and the image and then position them independently. Say if I want to set my image position to 50%, then I would have code which looks like the following....

```css
#over{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
#img{
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  right:50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="over">
 <img src="img.png" id="img">
</div>
```

Comment: Just tell me if it works with all kinds of browsers, even though this is a basic thing that every browser must support (otherwise don't call it a browser)

Answer (score 0):

I add some more properties to the CSS. Like so:

```
div#over {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex; 
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for a long time, i also tried the solution to put the img at the center of the div, but for my case i just need this type of component on ajax loading progress so i simply tried the following solution, hope this helps for you!

```
<div id="loader" style="position: absolute;top: 0;right: 0;left: 0;bottom: 0;z-index: 1;background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) url('your_image_url') no-repeat center;background-size: 135px;display: none;"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#over {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Modify height value for your need.

Answer (score -1):

This should work.

**IMPORTANT FOR TEST:** To Run code snippet click left button **RUN code snippet**, then right link **Full page**

```css
#fader{
position:fixed;z-index: 10;
top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;
opacity: 0.8;background: black;
width:100%;height:100%;
text-align: center;
}
.faders{display:inline-block;height:100%;vertical-align:middle;}
.faderi{display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;}
```

```html
<div id="fader">
<span class="faders"></span>
<img class="faderi" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHF2K.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use bootstraps `align-items` and `justify-content`. See example below:

```
<div class="well" style="align-items:center;justify-content:center;">
    <img src="img_source" height="50px" width="50px"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I see over 30 answers and I haven't seen this one so I'm going to add it.
just add a **center** tag.

```
<div id="over" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%>
 <center>
    <img src="img.png">
 </center>
</div>
```