# CSS: how to vertically and horizontally align an image?

Tags: css

My page has space for an image that can be, say, a maximum 100x100 image. Users can upload any image dimension and the web application will resize it, maintaining aspect ration, to 100x100. So, it's possible for images to be resized to, say, 75x100 or 100x75, etc.

Regardless of the resized image's dimension, I want it to appear vertically and horizontally centered in its allocated space on the web page. How do I do this in CSS? Will I need a containing div, like this:

```
<div class="image_container">
     <image src="http://placehold.it/100x100/" height="100" width="100" alt=""/>
</div>
```

Anyway, sample CSS would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Align image in center and middle within div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888223/align-image-in-center-and-middle-within-div)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/zYx4g/
This will work on image of any size and in all browsers.

```
.image_container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #eee;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 300px;
}

.image_container img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
​
```

Comment: this does not fit inside the div!

Answer (score 17):

I know this is and old question already answered but now you can use flex

```
<div class="container">
    <img  src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vw;
}
.container img
{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/u63sdesa/) Demo

you can also customize the size of your container, some browser may not support flex you can check it here [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

Comment: Very nice! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Move your left top corner of the image to the middle and reset it half the image's width and height:

```
.image_container img{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -50px;
}
```

Comment: That would work for 100px by 100px images, but for other image sizes it won't work

Comment: If your image is 120x100px then it will slightly be right next to the middle. Try to imagine how the browser will apply the different CSS properties and you will understand why it won't work if the image size doesn't fit to the CSS properties.

Comment: It will not exceed the maximum dimensions.

Comment: OK, but if it for example is 80x100px, then it will be 10px left from the real middle. Again: Try to imagine how the browser applies the CSS properties and you will understand what my snipped does.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
.image_container {
    display:table-cell;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.image_container img {
    vertical-align:baseline;
}
```

Not 100% sure on browser compatibility, but should get you started in the right direction. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fJtwX/1/

Comment: Is the div wrapper necessary?

Comment: You said you want the image to appear horizontally and vertically aligned in the allocated space (being the DIV), so if that's the case you would need the DIV otherwise you'd just display the image

Comment: I was just looking at this way and table-cell doesnt work in IE7 and lower.

Comment: @SmithMart Ah yeh, I thought as much

Comment: @JamieBicknell, yes I wanted it to appear centered in an "allocated space." Does that mean I must use a div? Could I somehow rely on just the img tag? Also, what to do about `table-cell`?

Comment: As pointed out by @SmithMart it won't work in IE7 and lower. ZoltanToth's answer is pretty solid and more compatible.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: Zoltan Toth answered nicely.**

Jamie's answer works, if you want older browserer compatibilty then use a table?

I know i'll probably get moaned at, but theres nothing wrong with tables when used where needed!

http://jsfiddle.net/Yhq5h/11/

set your container up what ever size is needed, I'd need to see the page, but this should work on all browsers.

Comment: Yup, fair enough. I tried it using line height and for some reason it never worked, must have been a typo :)

Answer (score 1):

In case someone still needs this here's a way to do it with display table;

```css
.thumbnail { width:150px; height:150px; display: table; }

.thumbnail img { max-width:150px; max-height:150px; }

.thumbnailcontainer { display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align:center;}
```

```html
<article class="thumbnail">    
  <div class="thumbnailcontainer">
         <img id="Img1" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/QAOMIH7cgh0/0.jpg" />   
   </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Elias, for next times use the code format  (the`{}` button) to format your code it's easier to read and you don't need to add the dots inside the tags :p

Comment: @goto, i know sorry, i did use it but as i was typing the answer i saw that the html code wasn't showing up in the box below (i'm new here so i don't know if that's normal)

Comment: Don't worry Elias, I commented it for you to learn :) It usually needs a blank line before the codeblock it's maybe the source of your original formating problem. See you!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="blog-thumbnail">                
    <img src="img.jpg" alt="img">
</div>

.blog-thumbnail {
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.blog-thumbnail img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please add a few words to help explain your answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is the cleanest and simplest solition:

```
.center {
     position: absolute;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Just add "center" class to the image. If you dont get the desired outcome, it means your outer container may not be positioned.  Just add "border: 1px dashed red" to your outer container to debug.

This 100% works.