# Center 2 different images in css

Tags: css, image, center

How can I insert two images in css, center them ?

I would like to have something like that: [link](http://cl.ly/VwwF)

My actual css look like this, with one image centered :

```
position: absolute; 
top: 0; 
bottom:0; 
left: 0; 
right:0;
margin: auto;
```

Comment: What do you mean with making 2 images centered at the same time? I do not see how that works out in your link either. Also where is your HTML? What selector does that CSS use? Could you post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Thank you MdeSchaepmeester and mostafaznv ,for the my next question i will post a jsdiffle. I have figured it out with the post from oopsoft. Anyway i appreciate your support. :)

Comment: Thanks i have figured it out :). http://jsfiddle.net/SoSoDef/FYHTQ/

Answer (score 0):

u can use `margin-top` or `right` and set `position:absolute` for `img` element in css

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mostafaznv/Te7C7/)

**CSS:**

```
img{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:100px;
    right:25%;
    width:50%;
}
#leftdiv{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    background: #e7e7e7;
    height:500px;
    width:50%;

}
#rightdiv{
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    height:500px;
    width:50%;
    background: green;

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id='leftdiv'>
    <img src='http://icdn4.digitaltrends.com/image/microsoft_xp_bliss_desktop_image-650x0.jpg'/>
</div>
<div id='rightdiv'>
     <img src='http://icdn4.digitaltrends.com/image/microsoft_xp_bliss_desktop_image-650x0.jpg'/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mostafaznv. Really appreciate your help but now how can i add to the images a link ? Thanks again.

Comment: @SoSkandalouS **see this:** http://jsfiddle.net/mostafaznv/FYHTQ/1/  you must use `</a>` after `img` element

Comment: if my answer was useful, you can push vote up button ;)

Comment: Thangs again mate. I would like to vote, but at least i has to have 15 of reputation, at the moment i have only 4 :/. Soon as i can i will vote of course.

Answer (score 0):

modifying the answer of this example : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371355/css-how-to-vertically-and-horizontally-align-an-image)

check that [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zYx4g/219/)

css

```
.image_container {
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    background: #eee;
    text-align: center;
    float:left;
}

.image_container img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Html

```
<div class="image_container">
     <image src="http://placehold.it/100x100/" height="100" width="100" alt=""/>
</div>
<div class="image_container">
     <image src="http://placehold.it/100x100/" height="100" width="100" alt=""/>
</div>
```

,also you can check that [page](http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html)

Comment: Thanks oops oft. Really appreciate your help , but now how can i add to the images a link ? Thanks again. :)

Answer (score -2):

Set width for image container.

Set margin : 0 auto;

Comment: right!! you can set width and margin for do that! ( doroste dooste man! )