# css Image with fixed width and auto adjust height

Tags: css

I have a fixed div with the css **width: 400px; height: 280px;** but my image comes from various dimension, some are portrait some landscape. How do I fit/stretch/fill my image regardless of source size into the div size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have fixed size on `div` you can just set `height/width` of img to 100%.

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://cdn2.spectator.co.uk/files/2016/04/iStock_000069830477_Small.jpg">
</div>
```

If you want to fill `div` but you also want to keep image aspect ratio you can use `object-fit: cover` that is similar to `background-size: cover` when you use img as background.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://cdn2.spectator.co.uk/files/2016/04/iStock_000069830477_Small.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

@giorgi-parunov has the simplest and best method. owever if you want to use , I suggest that you use css to make the image responsive to the div.

```
img {
     max-width:100%;
     height: auto
}
```

You can also use `object-fit: cover`

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way yo do it , do it with background-image.

HTML`<div style="background-image: url("paper.gif"); background-size: cover; background-position: center;"></div>`

It is the best way to add your image to the div without Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this answer to fit any image in a container centered 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36063374/2894798
In  your case the code would be

```
 .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 400px; /*customize to your needs 100%*/
  height: 280px; /*customize to your needs*/
}
.container img
{
 max-width:100%;
 max-height:100%;
}
```

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/u6j6osqL/)