# Align image center in floated div

Tags: image, center

I have a loop to loaded logo image in floated div block, I been tried few tips from stackoverflow but have no luck to make the logo align center and middle within the div, all logo height are not fixed and might have different height for each:

```
<div style="float:left; width:80px; height:80px; padding:8px; border:1px solid #ccc;">
    <img width="78px" align="left" src="images/logo/logo1.jpg">     
</div>
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888223/align-image-in-center-and-middle-within-div. Also FYI, you probably want to put your styling into a CSS class and file. This helps declutter your HTML and is especially useful whenever you get into responsive design and can apply different stylings based on different displays

Answer (score 2):

Use positioning. The following worked for me...

With zoom to the center of the image (image fills the div):

```
    div{
        float:left;
        display:block;
        overflow:hidden;
        width: 70px; 
        height: 70px;  
        position: relative;
    }
    div img{
        min-width: 70px; 
        min-height: 70px;
        max-width: 250%; 
        max-height: 250%;    
        top: -50%;
        left: -50%;
        bottom: -50%;
        right: -50%;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

Without zoom to the center of the image (image does **not** fill the div):

```
   div{
        float:left;
        display:block;
        overflow:hidden;
        width: 100px; 
        height: 100px;  
        position: relative;
    }
    div img{
        width: 70px; 
        height: 70px; 
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        bottom: 50%;
        right: 50%;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You really should move your CSS out of the `style` attribute and into a file like `style.css` if you have not done so.  But if you really have to you can place the code below into inline styles like you have now.

Remove the `align="left"` attribute from your image tag and set the image's display to `block`.  This will allow `margin: 0 auto;` to center your image for you inside the containing DIV.

Looks like you'll have to replicate a `<table>` with CSS to get the vertical centering you desire. Table cells allow vertical centering. To do this I've added and additional DIV with a class of `.container`. The `.container` DIV has it's display set to `table` and the `.image-container` DIV, which is acting like a table cell, has it's display set to `table-cell`.

**CSS**

```
.container {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: table;
}
.image-container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.image-container img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="image-container">
          <img src="images/logo/logo1.jpg">
     </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MJ5j4/

Comment: it will horizontally center the image but not vertically and it is same as `text-align:center` used

Comment: @anku_radhey You are correct. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

just create a class "centerImgWrapper", and wrap all your "center" Images anywhere in the Code with divs.

Thats pure CSS

```
.centerImgWrapper {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;}

.centerImgWrapper img {
 left: 0;
 right:0;
 top: 0;
 bottom:0;
 max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 margin:auto;
 position:absolute;
}
```

Just Check out the Fiddle. 
[MyFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8r6yu3xe/2/)

Dave

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get it in the middle inside the div, have you tried:

```
<div style="width:800px; height:800px; padding:8px; border:1px solid #ccc;">
        <img width="78px" src="mobiIconGreenGray.gif" style="margin-left:50%; margin-top:50%;">     
    </div>
```

I used "margin-left:50%; margin-top:50%;" INSIDE the IMG tag and got rid of the "align" and "float" attribute. I probably wouldn't want to use "align" in this case.
Either way, I hope it helps.

Comment: I think you're attempting to center the DIV not the image with what you have above.

Comment: I just edited it, you're right. now it's in the middle INSIDE the div

Comment: Using `margin-left: 50%;` will push the image's left side to the middle of the DIV along with `margin-top: 50%;` pushing the image's top side to the middle of the DIV.  This does not center it.  This places the image's top left corner in the middle of the containing DIV.

Answer (score 0):

Images are more or less displayed as inline-blocks. So you can just set `text-align: center;` on the styles of the container div.

Getting something to be vertically aligned in the middle is complicated with css. If you're going to be dynamically placing the logo with JavaScript anyway, you can save yourself trouble and just center it vertically by specifying the margins with JavaScript.

Check out this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jyvFN/1/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="logo" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var logo = document.getElementById('logo');
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var margin = (container.clientHeight - logo.clientHeight) / 2;
logo.style.marginTop = margin + "px";
logo.style.marginBottom = margin + "px";
```

Answer (score -1):

Why didn't you set align of the image center?
Then your code should be:

```
<div style="float:left; width:80px; height:80px; padding:8px; border:1px solid #ccc;">
<img width="78px" align="center" src="images/logo/logo1.jpg">
```

And I think it's also problem of the ratio of the image width vs the div block + it's padding and border.
Try to set it balance.

Comment: Do not use the align attribute.  This attribute is being fazed out.