# Align image in center and middle within div with display:table-caption

Tags: html, css, alignment, center, vertical-alignment

I want to place an image inside a div 200x200px and also the image must be centered horizontally and vertically.

I start with SO question ["Align image in center and middle within div"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888223/align-image-in-center-and-middle-within-div) and try out the *first* answer:

```
#over img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

**It doesn't work...** [see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fx4pE/)

Then, I continue with the *second* answer:

```
<div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center">
<img src="img.png">
</div>
```

**It doesn't work...** [see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exKqq/)

Finally, I try this:

```
display: table-caption;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

**and it seems to work!** [see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NeN2t/)

Can somebody explain to me why the first two approaches fail to keep the outer div to `200x200px`? I see very similar code snippets and can't understand what really makes the difference. Thank you in advance...

Comment: Second example seems to work if you use height instead of line-height (which I don't know why you'd want to use in the first place).

Answer (score 2):

Change line-height to height and they will respect your wishes :)

Simplified it a bit for you by using background-image and remove the other element.

```
background-image: url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
```

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/NeN2t/2/

Comment: The `background` approach was what I tried first but changed my mind because I wanted to use lazy loading with echo.js

Comment: don't use table-caption for that, see my fiddle how to center images in a div, now you can even fade it and write over it :)

Comment: Ok, you could still use a javascript function to call on page load to insert the image late. all document resources are always loaded at the end of the document.

Answer (score 1):

Second answer - you forget to wrap table-cell in table, or select height for container.

```
<div class="wrap">
<div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center">
    <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" />
</div>
</div>
```

see [JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/exKqq/1/)

And I have one more method, for modern browsers, may be it help you. 
[DEMO for modern browsers](http://jsfiddle.net/exKqq/3/) this method is more useful when you do responsive design or fluid design.

Answer (score 0):

Use positioning instead of table-cell. The following worked for me...

With zoom to the center of the image (image fills the div):

```
    div{
        display:block;
        overflow:hidden;
        width: 70px; 
        height: 70px;  
        position: relative;
    }
    div img{
        min-width: 70px; 
        min-height: 70px;
        max-width: 250%; 
        max-height: 250%;    
        top: -50%;
        left: -50%;
        bottom: -50%;
        right: -50%;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

Without zoom to the center of the image (image does **not** fill the div):

```
   div{
        display:block;
        overflow:hidden;
        width: 100px; 
        height: 100px;  
        position: relative;
    }
    div img{
        width: 70px; 
        height: 70px; 
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        bottom: 50%;
        right: 50%;
        position: absolute;
    }
```