# Center unknow image size with overflow hidden

Tags: css, image, center

How do I

- vertically center an image (crop top and bottom)
- have the image size to have width:100%
- it's parent having overflow hidden?

  some solutions I've tried was
  [Align image in center and middle within div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888223/align-image-in-center-and-middle-within-div)
  and as well as others.

html

```
<div> 
    <a href="#"><img src=".."></a>
</div>
```

css

```
div {
  height:60px;
  width:200px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow:hidden;
}

img {
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:100%;
}
```

heres a codepen for it
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXRoxp

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have it vertically centered but the image has height 150px and your containing `<div>` is only 60px high. Making the `<div>` bigger than 150px and you will see it is aligned correctly.

**EDIT**

If you are intentionally trying to clip the image within the `<div>`, remove the `<img>` element and set it as the background using CSS.

```
div {
  height:60px;
  width:200px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  display:table-cell;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: no-repeat center url('http://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis4_big.jpg') ;
}
```