# How to add text underneath the centered image

Tags: html, css

On this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888223/align-image-in-center-and-middle-within-div) there is a [great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18830421/4907552) on how to add centred image to the page.

> - Pure CSS solution
> - Not breaking the document flow (no floats or absolute positioning)
> - Cross browser compatibility (even IE6)
> - Completely responsive.
> - vertically centered

The solution http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/d89xh/

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#over {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.Centerer {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.Centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="over">
  <span class="Centerer"></span>
  <img class="Centered" src="http://th07.deviantart.net/fs71/200H/f/2013/236/d/b/bw_avlonas_a5_beach_isles_wallpaper_image_by_lemnosexplorer-d6jh3i7.jpg" />
</div>
```

But how to modify that solution to add an extra text just underneath the centered image so it will be always centered as well.

[image: Picture of desired output]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `<figure>` and `<figcaption>`:

```
<figure>
  <img />
  <figcaption>Image</figcaption>
</figure>
```

And give the parent element, `text-align: center;`.

**Snippet**

```css
.center {text-align: center;}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250?text=IMG" alt="">
    <figcaption>Hello</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

**Preview:**

[image]

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0p53fxgk/**

**Preview:**

[image]

**Cross Browser Check**

- Internet Explorer 9
- IE Edge
- Firefox
- Chrome
- Opera

For IE below 9, you can use:

```
figure, figcaption {display: block;}
```

Comment: Is that solution crossborswer like the one I mentioned in the question?

Comment: @sreginogemoh Yes buddy. Updated in your fiddle too.

Comment: OK I see. Is there any way to make it vertically centered as well line in the example I mentioned ?

Comment: @sreginogemoh Yes possible. Do you knwo the dimensions of the image?

Comment: Yes that will be about `487x437px`

Comment: @sreginogemoh Awesome. Then it is easy... Lemme create a jsbin for you.

Comment: @sreginogemoh Have any height for the `#over`. See this **http://output.jsbin.com/hetoridaqi** being responsive. But for fixed width. It is always centered and vertically middle.

Comment: @sreginogemoh ***ps: Works for IE 6 as well.***