# Centering an image in div tag while it is responsive

Tags: html, css

I want to display an image on the webpage. The image is long enough having fixed height. So, when someone checks responsiveness by decreasing screen-size it should remove the extra size from that div(which is happening).

I don't know the particular term. So, I will try to explain. it should be shown from the centre point. If image is "abcdefgh". Assume 'a','b'... all are grid number. The default behaviour when screen size will be relatively half is "abcd", but I want to display "cdef".

I gave overflow: hidden to remove extra image out of div. I tried margin-left, margin-right both auto. But, it is only required when the image is less than div size.

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="border:4px solid black; height:200px;overflow:hidden;text-align:center;">
    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(130).jpg" alt="Paris" style="width:100%;height:200px;">
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post what you have tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Align image in center and middle within div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888223/align-image-in-center-and-middle-within-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `object-fit: cover` to 'crop' the image responsively

Comment: But, on full screen, it is stretching the image and hiding details. Can I get default image in full screen. As the image I gave is a full size desktop image

Comment: solved my problem. It was stretching due to heigh of image is more than height of div wrap. But, for me height is constant. So, vertically height fit not required. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set fixed size for image an use `object-fit: cover` in css.

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 4px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="img" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(130).jpg" alt="Paris">
</div>
```

Comment: But, on full screen, it is stretching the image and hiding details. Can I get default image in full screen. As the image I gave is a full size desktop image

Comment: solved my problem. It was stretching due to heigh of image is more than height of div wrap. But, for me height is constant. So, vertically height fit not required. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used `object-fit: cover;`, this works.

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="border:4px solid black; height:200px;overflow:hidden;text-align:center;">
    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(130).jpg" alt="Paris" style="width:100%;height:200px;">
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But, on full screen, it is stretching the image and hiding details. Can I get default image in full screen. As the image I gave is a full size desktop image

Comment: solved my problem. It was stretching due to heigh of image is more than height of div wrap. But, for me height is constant. So, vertically height fit not required. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Only object-fit: cover will not work. It also needs `width` and `height` values. For best practice give `height` value. Please this value should not in percentage(%). And give image width: 100% and height: 100%. It will work.

```css
.parentDiv {
  border: 4px solid black;
  width: 80%;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv">
  <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(130).jpg" alt="Paris"><div>
```

Please check this link: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7m0qpy4f)