# What is the most simple and effective way to prvent images from flowing out of their parent <div>

Tags: html, css, image

I am having some trouble with the code below. What is supposed to happen is the image rests neatly inside the card with some padding around the edges. Instead, it flows out of the parent div.

Code:

```html
<div class="card greeting">
    <h3>Good Morning, admin</h3>
    <p class = "greeting-text">Mornings are the start of new ideas.</p>
    <img src = "<?php echo ASSETS_PATH . 'images/park.png' ?>">
</div>
```

```css
.card {
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  background-color: var(--page-background-color);
  box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 13px 0;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  transition: .3s;
  color: var(--font-color);
  object-fit: contain;
}

.greeting{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  background-size: 55px;
  padding:10px;
}

.greeting img{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  background-size: 55px;
  padding:10px;
}

.greeting .greeting-text{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

What would be a simple solution for this? My goal is to have the image neatly inside the card.

I have tried `object-fit:contain` and other solutions but either I didn't do them correctly, or something else is wrong.

Comment: Overflow hidden on parent. 

Don't have time now but consider checking if this has already been answered.

Comment: Its cuts off the image.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888223/align-image-in-center-and-middle-within-div/18830421

Answer (score 0):

Don't think too much, you are not giving image as a background image, so need to use background properties

```
.greeting img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: It still is flowing out of the parent div `.card`

Comment: Here you are: https://codepen.io/balFB373/pen/RwRmqrK

Comment: remove height in your styles for the card it will enable full height image

Comment: for the parent `.card`?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation. One of the effective method is to use

```
<div class="container">
```

this helped me out.
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_containers.asp Check out this article.