# `margin: 0 auto;` and `width:50%` combination doesn't center my div

Tags: html, css

I have some issues when trying to center vertically and horizontally divs that are inside other divs.

This is what I'm trying to do:

[image]

I've also read [How to horizontally center a <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/114543) and [How to center a "position: absolute" element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8508275).

This question isn't a duplicate to neither of those, because I don't want to center a div that has `position:absolute`. I want to center a div with no `position` attribute that is inside a div that has `position:absolute`.

`margin: 0 auto;` and `width:50%` **does not work**.

Aligning images, text and buttons require different methods each, which I do not know.

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: url(back-image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: gray;
}

html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

#container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.top-container,
.center-container,
.side-container {
  position: absolute;
}

.top-container {
  left: 20%;
  top: 0;
  height: 30%;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.center-container {
  left: 20%;
  top: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
}

.side-container {
  left: 70%;
  top: 14%;
  height: 80%;
  width: 30%;
  background: green;
}

.top-container #logo {
  /* background: black;     */
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
}


/* .top-container #logo img {
    display: inline-block;
} */

.top-container .title {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  /* margin: 0 auto; */
  background: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.center-container .title {
  /* margin: 0 auto; */
  background: greenyellow;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

#text-box {
  color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: black;
}

.center-container #text-box {
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
}

#text-box p {
  margin: 10px 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}

#text-box span {
  color: cyan;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: right;
}

.side-container .title {
  /* margin: 0 auto; */
  background: greenyellow;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

#settings-button {
  width: 50%;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid red;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="top-container">
    <div id="logo"><img url="logo.png"></div>
    <div class="title">
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="center-container">
    <div class="text-box">%PLACEHOLDER_1%</div>
  </div>
  <div class="side-container">
    <div id="text-box">
      <p>URL: %PLACEHOLDER_URL%</p>
      <p>URL Refresh Rate: %PLACEHOLDER_URR%</p>
      <p>Brightness: %PLACEHOLDER_Brightness%</p>
    </div>
    <input id="settings-button" type="submit" name="" value="Settings">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the result:

[image]

There are some issues that I don't know how to fix:

- Can't center the image that's inside `#logo`.
  Its `div` has `background: black`. It is using `width:50%` and it is centered nicely inside `.top-container` but the `img` does not center to the center of `#logo` div. 
  I've tried: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4888118) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/a/18516474), but it only made things even worse.
- Can't center `#settings-button` inside `.side-container`.** It's the same as `#logo`.
  `.center-container .title` and `.side-container .title` behave like they are set at `top= 5px`. **Why aren't they placed at the beginning of their wrapper divs: `.center-container` and `.side-container` respectively ?**

I've used `text align: center` for the `.title` which centered the text only horizontally. **What does it need to be done for the text to center vertically as well ?**

I've used `width:100%` for the text `div`s because I don't need the `div`s to be centered. Changing `width:` to whatever percent still keeps it centered.

I've tried adding `display:grid` and `flex` and `inline-block` but they only make things even worse.

This is as far as I am capable of going.

Comment: Jup, either duplicate, or remove the absolute and try to style it with block elements.

Comment: Add `display: block` to those elements. Or use `text-align: center` on the container. The `margin: 0 auto; with: xxx` trick works for block elements.

Comment: I am not trying to center the divs that have their `position` set to `absolute`. I am trying to center divs that are inside divs that have `position: absolute;`.

Comment: For the titles not at the top, I can't see a `.side-container .title` element, but the problem seem to be the default top margin on the H1 tags inside it.

Comment: for the logo image - have you tried `text-align: center` on the logo div? Same with side container - but then you would have to re-align the #textbox to left

Comment: @Pete I've tried `text-align: center` on the `#logo` div. It did not work.
@arieljuod I do have a `.side-container .title` element. Changing `h1` element's `margin` and `padding` fixed the lip issue.

Comment: If you want this layout to be responsive on smaller devices, you will need to take a different approach.  I'd recommend becoming familiar with either [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [CSS Grid](https://learncssgrid.com/)

Comment: @RutherfordWonkington That would take a long time. I need this done yesterday. I hope I could get a piece of advice on how to center those damned divs.

Comment: Adding `display:block;` to the `#settings-button` made it center. And the image was set to left with this `background: url(logo.png) left no-repeat;` . Changing it to `center` fixed it.

Comment: Can I hope for a fix to this ? 
https://i.postimg.cc/DZxmF6Mh/Screenshot-at-2019-05-10-17-01-23.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attempted to fix your code example, but had difficulty relating the various parts of your question to your code example. Instead, I'll tell you how to fix it yourself.

Centering vertically is quite tricky - unless you use flexbox or CSS Grid. Then it's dead easy. Honestly, if you spend about 30 mins fiddling with flexbox you'll have it down - and the layout is straight-forward and makes sense, unlike floats.

There is a reason why Bootstrap re-did their entire platform from Bootstrap3 to Bootstrap4, primarily to change from using floats to flexbox.

Flexbox requires two things:

1. A parent container *(e.g. DIV, section, aside, p, etc)*
2. One or more child elements *(e.g. div, p, img, etc)*

You turn flexbox ***on*** on the parent: `display:flex;`

Then, there are various *switches*. Some are set on the parent (as in the case of `justify-content`) but others might be set on the items (as with `flex-grow:1`)

[YouTube tutorial - fast-paced and best-of-breed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k32voqQhODc)

[Here is a great cheatsheet](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/) for Flexbox.

***Watch the tutorial and in 40 mins from now your problem will be solved -- and you'll know flexbox.***

<sub>P.S. I have no connection to the video or its presenter - I was fortunate to discover it, and now pass it along.</sub>